# Efficiently Managing Types in TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types

I've been working on a large TS project for work and absolutely love it. When the project started we stored all of our custom-defined interfaces and types in a single `types.ts` file, which just exported each of them. That way, we could `import` only the types we needed in each module (in our case, React components). In this sense, we essentially have a `global.d.ts` file as defined [here](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/project/globals.html) with the added benefit of it actually being a module because of the `export` syntax in `types.ts`.

Of course, the project has scaled and it's really time to move these definitions elsewhere. My question is how to actually build out separate `.d.ts` files to do this. Should I have separate `.d.ts` files for each component (or perhaps component group) and then reference them in a single `index.d.ts`? Should I just stick with what I have? Other suggestions? Really I'm just looking for advice on how other devs manage type definitions in a scalable, maintainable way. We are using TS 2.4.2 with React, Redux, redux-saga, and webpack.

Comment: I give multiple components their own .d.ts files and import them specifically where needed.

There's nothing wrong with your current setup, if it's not causing you any issues now maybe it's not something worth solving?

Comment: I assume you're then letting your `tsconfig.json` know about those definitions, yeah? Are you doing that by referencing all your individual `.d.ts` files in a single one and passing this to `tsconfing` in your `types` field? I'm mostly just curious about managing type architecture and ensuring that the TypeScript compiler "sees" everything it needs to.